# Finding the number of different values of an attribute

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I am writing an APS.NET MVC 5 application in C#, using a MongoDB database. Suppose I have a `MongoDatabase` object called `my_db`, which contains a `MongoCollection` of `Label` objects, called `labels`. Each `Label` object has a few attributes, one of which is a string called `tag`. Each `tag` value may be shared across different `Labels`, such that some `Label` objects will have the same value for `tag`.

I want to find out how many different values for `tag` there are in this collection, and store these values in an array of some sort.

I'm fairly new to MongoDB, so I don't really know how to do this. All I have done so far is get `labels`:

```
var labels = my_db.GetCollection<Label>("labels");
```

But I'm stuck as to what I need to do now. I could manually iterate through each `Label` in `labels`, and check whether that `Label`'s `tag` attribute has already been seen before. But is there a neater way to do this with a MongoDB function? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There is a MongoDB method for this: [`distinct`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/), that should exist in any API.

Answer (score 0):

As you are doing this on MVC 5 c# application, MongoDB provides C# LINQ Driver which will help your querying  MongoDB using LINQ.

http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/use-linq-queries-with-csharp-driver/

Hope this helps.

```
var query = (from e in labels.AsQueryable<labelClass>()
                  select e.tag).Distinct()
```